# How to create a shared registry key for WoW64 and x64 Processes

Tags: c#, wix, registry, wow64

Is there some way to create a custom (WoW64) shared registry key?

By default some registry keys are shared and others are redirected (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384253%28VS.85%29.aspx)). But I want to create a custom registry key under HKLM\Software which should be shared. I'm looking for a solution in C# (maybe P/Invoke) and WIX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the [`KEY_WOW64_32KEY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384129(v=VS.85).aspx) flag to [`RegCreateKeyEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724844(v=VS.85).aspx) (or [`RegOpenKeyEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724897(v=VS.85).aspx)) you will always access the 32 bit registry.

I couldn't find this flag (nor [`KEY_WOW64_64KEY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384129(v=VS.85).aspx) which is the same but for 64bit access) in the Wix source code, so you might need to use pinvoke.

Comment: Though this is possible, I'd rather create a shared key.

Comment: @Michael What do you mean by "Shared Key" I don't know if such a thing  exists

Comment: A shared key ist a key, wich is not redirected (see the MSDN Article, I've mentioned in the Question). But I couldn't find anything else about this, so I think yours is the solution.